# How to target a .sln file in another directory, when running the dotnet publish command inside of a workflow

Tags: c#, workflow

I am experiencing the following issue when attempting to deploy a project to the test environment through a workflow:

*MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.*

Where the issue is being triggered in the workflow:

```
- name: dotnet publish
  run: dotnet publish -c SIT -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}\projectName-api
```

env.DOTNET_ROOT - C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\projectName-Api

The solution file is another directory ***(.projectName/Project.sln)*** which is why I think this issue is occurring.

What I would like to know - Is there a way to run a separate command to reference the solution file when

`dotnet publish -c SIT -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}\projectName-api` is triggered?

If not, what would be the best way to resolve this?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!